# How to make python3.8 access modules of python3.6?

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, emoji

I have python3.8. I have installed the module `emoji` with the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-emoji
```

I then finished the installation with

```
$ git clone https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji.git
$ cd emoji
$ python setup.py install
```

However, the program `test.py` given by

```
import emoji
print(emoji.emojize('Python is :thumbs_up:'))
```

Runs under python2 and python3.6, but does not run under python3.8. When I do `python3.8 test.py` I receive the message:

```
AttributeError: module 'emoji' has no attribute 'emojize'
```

How can I run the module with python3.8?

Note 1: I use Xubuntu (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)

Note 2: I tried to install emoji with `python3.8 -m pip`. I receive the message No module named pip.

Note 3: When I do `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, I receive the message python3-pip is already the newest version.

Comment: maybe try `python3.8 setup.py install`?

Comment: FWIW, the most recent version that `emoji` officially supports is [Python 3.7](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/commit/243201bcb0978dc061327bb9ed4530e177d7f5b0#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298), though that shouldn't prevent it from working with 3.8.

Comment: @wjandrea When I try it, I receive the message Traceback; File setup.py, line 13, in <module> from setuptools import setup; ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'

Comment: Hmm, you might have to use a virtualenv, I'm not sure.

Comment: @wjandrea Do you have a good reference about creating a virtualenv and using it for this purpose? Could you write an answer about this?